# how to set selected elements in DevExpress' CheckedComboBoxEdit

Tags: devexpress, checkedlistbox

I'm a newbie for DevExpress controls. I have a DevExpress `checkedComboBoxEdit` control that is populated by data from SQL Server using Linq. Populating the checkedComboBox elements worked fine but I couldn't figure out how to set the selected elements.

The DB table contains three fields

- id (Value Member),
- Role (Display Member)
- Applies (contains 0 for *unselected* and 1 for *selected*)

I want to select the checkbox elements based on the Applies field. How can I do this? Or is there a better way of doing this by modifying the database table? Or is there a CheckedComboBox property to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should find all you need in the [DevExpress online doumentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic).  In particular:

> To initialize the check items' values and display text with values of
>   these fields, assign the names of the fields to the
>   [RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.ValueMember](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit_ValueMembertopic) and
>   [RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.DisplayMember](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit_DisplayMembertopic) properties.

So in your case, you should assign 'Role' to the `DisplayMember` property and 'Applies' to the `ValueMember` property (rather than 'id').

Answer (score 0):

To Unchecked all items in CheckedComboBoxEdit

```
  For i = 0 To CheckedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Count - 1
       clUSER_ID.CheckedComboBoxEdit1.Items.Item(i).CheckState = 
       CheckState.Unchecked
   Next
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.